# Javascript Object returning undefined for a passed key

Tags: javascript, dictionary, javascript-objects

I am trying to build a JS object so that when I pass a key (account number) to my function, it returns the corresponding value (account balance). But when I run the code, it gives undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<script>

var accountNumbers = {};
acccountNumbers = {
    "100002149056": 250000.23,
    "100002149056": 11234567.98,
    "100027837199": 100000.98,
    "100027837289": 9567.98,
    "100027837299": 34567.98
}

function returnBalance(accountNo){
    var balance = 0.000;
    for (var acn in accountNumbers){
        if(accountNumbers.hasOwnProperty(acn)){
            balance = accountNumbers[acn];
            break;
        }
        return balance;
    }
}

console.log("Balance in acount no 100002149056 is: " +returnBalance("100002149056"));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone please point out what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you simply return `acccountNumbers[accountNo]`? Using `for...in` is an overkill here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var accountNumbers = {"100002149056": 250000.23,
    "100002149056": 11234567.98,
    "100027837199": 100000.98,
    "100027837289": 9567.98,
    "100027837299": 34567.98};
    
function returnBalance(accountNo){
    var balance = accountNumbers[accountNo];
    if(!balance)
      balance = 0.000;
    return balance;
}

console.log("Balance in account no 100027837299 is: " +returnBalance("100027837299"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two objects created here:
`acccountNumbers` and `accountNumbers`. Spelling mistake is causing this issue.
Also, code doesn't make sense. Please explain what you aare trying to achieve here. Below code will give you something meaningful but it can be improved as there is no need of a loop.

```
function returnBalance(accountNo){
var balance = 0.000;
for (var acn in accountNumbers){
    if(accountNumbers.hasOwnProperty(accountNo)){
        balance = accountNumbers[accountNo];
        break;
    }
}
return balance;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please point out what is it that I am doing wrong?

Multiple things

- You are returning from `for-loop` and this statement will get executed after the first iteration itself.
- You are not checking for the parameter `accountNo` at all.

Just make it

```
function returnBalance(accountNo){
    return accountNumbers[ accountNo ] || 0.000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping the whole Object is wrong, Just check is Object contains that key which you want (in your case Account number) or not and then return the value accordingly.

```
 function returnBalance(accountNo) {
    var balance = 0.000;

    if (acccountNumbers.hasOwnProperty(accountNo))
        balance = acccountNumbers[accountNo];

    return balance;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning inside the for loop, once you call to break it skip your return statement. Here I have moved return statement outside the for loop.

```
    function returnBalance(accountNo) {
      var balance = 0.000;
      for (var acn in accountNumbers) {
        if (accountNumbers.hasOwnProperty(acn)) {
          balance = accountNumbers[acn];
          break;
        }
      }
      //moved this outside the for loop
      return balance;
    }
```

Comment: and you can simply remove for loop just keep if and return the value withing the if                                                                                                                       `  function returnBalance(accountNo) {
  if (accountNumbers.hasOwnProperty(accountNo)) {
    return accountNumbers[accountNo] || 0.000;
  }
}`